# Sort entities by empty ArrayCollection?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities: Client and User. Users can be assigned to clients (many-to-many; one user can manage many clients, client can be managed by many users). In my application I have list of clients. Is there a way to display clients without assigned users on top of the list, using Doctrine? Or should I just use findAll() and sort in PHP?

EDIT: So basically, by creating @ORM\ManyToMany relationship I have 3 tables in MySQL: clients, users, and clients_of_users (with client_id and user_id columns). Using normal SQL:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.surname, COUNT(cof.user_id) as `Number of Users` 
FROM clients c 
LEFT JOIN clients_of_users cof ON c.id = cof.client_id 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY `Number of Users` ASC
```

With this query I am getting result:

```
1    Name1    Surname1    0
6    Name6    Surname6    0
5    Name5    Surname5    1 
7    Name7    Surname7    1 
3    Name3    Surname3    2 
4    Name4    Surname4    3 
2    Name2    Surname2    4
```

So yay! I have clients without users on top. Finally I want to have this list sorted by client id, but still with clients without users on top, so result would look like this:

```
1    Name1    Surname1    0
6    Name6    Surname6    0
2    Name2    Surname2    4 
3    Name3    Surname3    2 
4    Name4    Surname4    3 
5    Name5    Surname5    1 
7    Name7    Surname7    1
```

So, all of this I would like to achieve using Symfony2 / Doctrine way. Is this possible?

Comment: findAll() and sort in php is deprecated with large db. Use your repo to build a querybuilder

Comment: Use this for query all object of the repository and sort by name in DES order `$repo->findBy(array(),array('name','DESC');`

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible directly in your Repository with a specific method:

```
public function findClientOrderedByUser()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->select('c')

                    /***/

                    ->orderBy('c.user', 'DESC');


    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: Unfortunately in this case it doesn't work. As I wrote in my question this is many-to-many relation, so in  Client entity I have protected $users, and in User entity I have protected $clients - both defined in __construct() method of both entities as ArrayCollection(). When I am using Your method I am receiving error: QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 56 near 'users DESC': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Comment: When I am using this query: 'SELECT c FROM Client c JOIN c.users u' I am receiving list of clients with assigned users on them, but what I want is list of ALL clients, where these without assigned users are on top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right then it is a very basic question. You should add a ClientRepository class and add a custom function that uses ORDER BY in the query.You could build this query with DQL or with the querybuilder. a close example can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).